# ESTA: Do I need to tell all my trip itinerary?

Tags: esta, road-trips, itineraries

I'm an Italian citizen and I'm planning to visit the USA for a trip of 2 weeks, driving a car from LA to San Francisco.

Reading the ESTA declaration, I found a part where I need to declare *Information of a person to contact in USA*, with name, address, city and so on.

Assuming that I'm more interested on an "on the road" trip, which means I'll want to stop somewhere casually and take a room when I'm tired of driving/visiting.

How can I sincerely answer these questions without the risk of having my ESTA revoked?

Comment: Just put where you are staying the 1st night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it is not a mandatory field. It depends on the reason you apply to ESTA (e.g. business or visiting).

The information could be used by the immigration officer to ask further questions (about how you will sustain in US). If you are Italian, with a return ticked (and just 2 weeks), and a credit or debit card, it shouldn't be a problem.

BTW the way to add address is also not ideal. You cannot give a hotel name, but just an address, and from my experience it is also very prone to get the data wrong. (just by copying the address from the booking website). So I'm convinced that this question is just for convenience to immigration office (and to you, to have clear ideas).

Comment: assuming to your answer, i wont travel with a credit card(don't have one), but with a debit one, is still a good sign ?

Comment: No, immigration won't care if you use a debit or credit card.

Comment: It's not mandatory to specify an address although I've also been asked at airline check-in to provide a hotel address when flying to the US, so you might want to have something in mind. It's perfectly legitimate to give the name of where you'll be staying the first night, or even where you think you'll be staying the first night. You certainly don't need to provide a full itinerary. The ESTA website has the most enormous set of guidelines and help so really just read it.